# how to get array of services in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in linux shell script I am using below line to get list of all services so that I can find which are running further or not, if not then I will try to start them , if failed to start then log entry.

```
service_array=($(service --status-all|rev|cut -d " " -f 1|rev))
```

but for services which have question mark in subscript it does not take the entry like below.

```
[ ? ]  appport
[ ? ]  console-setup
```

for these entry it just give output on the console as it is, not entry in array. So what is the issue in the above line

Comment: Your pipeline isn't handling standard error output.  `service`s with `[ ? ]` have unknown status and written to `stderr`.

Comment: @dilip_jindal JohnB deserves the check mark instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
service_array=($(exec service --status-all | sed 's|.* ||'))
```

Or better:

```
readarray -t service_array < <(exec service --status-all | sed 's|.* ||')
```

Without sed:

```
readarray -t service_array < <(exec service --status-all)
service_array=("${service_array[@]##* }")
```

Yet another:

```
service_array=()
while read service; do service_array+=("$service"); done < <(exec service --status-all | sed 's|.* ||')
```

Or

```
service_array=()
while read service; do service_array+=("$service"); done < <(exec service --status-all)
service_array=("${service_array[@]##* }")
```

And an alternative to `sed` is to use `awk`:

```
... | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Comment: These do nothing with `[ ? ]` statuses, which is what OP asked about.  They are all still written to `stderr`.

Comment: @JohnB I see. If that's the case please do tell the OP about that.

Comment: Whether or not your answer fits the question, I can appreciate all the different variations you offered of parsing the output into an array.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your pipeline is not handling standard error output.  The `?` means the service has an unknown status and is written to `stderr`.  Unfortunately, `man service` is lacking in this information.

What `--status-all` checks for is if `status` is being handled as an argument in the corresponding `/etc/init.d` script of the `service`.  If not, it prints the status of `[ ? ]` to standard error.

Your command pipeline will catch all statuses if you run it like this:

```
service_array=($(service --status-all 2>&1|rev|cut -d " " -f 1|rev))
```

If you want only the known status:

```
service_array=($(service --status-all 2>/dev/null|rev|cut -d " " -f 1|rev))
```

If you want only unknown status:

```
service_array=($(service --status-all 2>&1 1>/dev/null|rev|cut -d " " -f 1|rev))
```

Comment: I gave you my +1 buddy :) Mine has had many options but you solved the actual cause of the problem so your answer deserves the +15 instead :) Cheers.

Comment: Thanks dude, no worries.  I was just wishing I could give my accepted answer to someone else yesterday :)

Comment: @konsolebox No worries, I will scratch his back on your behalf. Just a little extra.

Answer (score 0):

There could be spaces in the end of lines. I would use this better

```
echo -e '[ ? ]  appport\n[ ? ]  console-setup' | grep -o '[^ ]\+[[:blank:]]*$'
```